# Magento 2 - quick installing host or scripts with sample data

Tags: magento2

I need to quickly setup 3 different Magento 2 demo sites with sample data.

After trying:

DigitalOcean, Justhost, Ampps and Mamp and having installation problems with all of them, I've decided to look for either an installer script that will install Magento 2 with sample data or a host or software or something that I can just run and it installs Magento 2 with the sample data or something that I can use as after weeks of nightmares I'm about to just give up on Magento 2.

Any advises on my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Vagrant or Docker to deploy Magento 2 on DigitalOcean.